# The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'. How can I fix it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I got this **The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'.** for my code.

```
class _LogoutState extends State<Logout> {
  String uid = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    uid = '';
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.*then*((val) {  **The error is here
      setState(() {
        this.uid = val.uid;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because it is not an **asynchronous function**.

FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser is a **user type getter**, so what you could do would be this.

```
class _LogoutState extends State<Logout> {
  String uid = '';
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    setUid();
    super.initState();
  }

  void setUid() {
    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      setState(() {
        this.uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
      });
    }
  }
}
```